# Erro após realizar o migrations (backend .Net)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, back-end

Meu backend é construído em .NET, e ao incluir uma certa tabela na solução, me apareceu o seguinte erro:

> Cannot create more than one clustered index on table 'dbo.Favorit'.
>   Drop the existing clustered index 'PK_dbo.Favorit' before
>   creating another.

O que seria isso? E como resolver? Obrigado!

Esse código foi gerado após o comando `Add-Migration CreateFavorit` e `update-database`:

```
namespace appService.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Annotations;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class CreateFavorit : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Favorit",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128,
                            annotations: new Dictionary<string, AnnotationValues>
                            {
                                { 
                                    "ServiceTableColumn",
                                    new AnnotationValues(oldValue: null, newValue: "Id")
                                },
                            }),
                        Nome = c.String(),
                        Lat_dest = c.Double(nullable: false),
                        Lon_dest = c.Double(nullable: false),
                        Id_usuario = c.String(),
                        Endereco = c.String(),
                        MeioTransporte = c.String(),
                        Id_usuario_2 = c.String(),
                        Version = c.Binary(nullable: false, fixedLength: true, timestamp: true, storeType: "rowversion",
                            annotations: new Dictionary<string, AnnotationValues>
                            {
                                { 
                                    "ServiceTableColumn",
                                    new AnnotationValues(oldValue: null, newValue: "Version")
                                },
                            }),
                        CreatedAt = c.DateTimeOffset(nullable: false, precision: 7,
                            annotations: new Dictionary<string, AnnotationValues>
                            {
                                { 
                                    "ServiceTableColumn",
                                    new AnnotationValues(oldValue: null, newValue: "CreatedAt")
                                },
                            }),
                        UpdatedAt = c.DateTimeOffset(precision: 7,
                            annotations: new Dictionary<string, AnnotationValues>
                            {
                                { 
                                    "ServiceTableColumn",
                                    new AnnotationValues(oldValue: null, newValue: "UpdatedAt")
                                },
                            }),
                        Deleted = c.Boolean(nullable: false,
                            annotations: new Dictionary<string, AnnotationValues>
                            {
                                { 
                                    "ServiceTableColumn",
                                    new AnnotationValues(oldValue: null, newValue: "Deleted")
                                },
                            }),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
                .Index(t => t.CreatedAt, clustered: true);

        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropIndex("dbo.Favorit", new[] { "CreatedAt" });
            DropTable("dbo.Favorit",
                removedColumnAnnotations: new Dictionary<string, IDictionary<string, object>>
                {
                    {
                        "CreatedAt",
                        new Dictionary<string, object>
                        {
                            { "ServiceTableColumn", "CreatedAt" },
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Deleted",
                        new Dictionary<string, object>
                        {
                            { "ServiceTableColumn", "Deleted" },
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Id",
                        new Dictionary<string, object>
                        {
                            { "ServiceTableColumn", "Id" },
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "UpdatedAt",
                        new Dictionary<string, object>
                        {
                            { "ServiceTableColumn", "UpdatedAt" },
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Version",
                        new Dictionary<string, object>
                        {
                            { "ServiceTableColumn", "Version" },
                        }
                    },
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Não sei se é pertinente, mas o banco é o SQLServer, microsft-azure o servidor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A mensagem de erro é causada pelo Entity Framework não ter uma
>   anotação para criar um índice agrupado, que não é uma chave primária.
>   O SDK móvel cria manualmente as instruções SQL corretas para definir o
>   CreateAt, como um índice de cluster de chave não primária.

Resolvido então colocando o seguinte código no Configuration.cs, que está no Migrations:

```
public Configuration()
{
   AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
   SetSqlGenerator("System.Data.SqlClient", new EntityTableSqlGenerator());
}
```

Adicionado o setSqlGenerator....